# Как называется технология, когда сайт загружается быстро, а какие-то данные в фоновом режиме?

Tags: php, reactjs, vue.js, frontend, backend

У меня несколько вопросов:

- Некоторые оптимизируют сайты таким образом: первым делом показывают каркас сайта, а в сами блоки, в фоновом режиме, по ajax подтягиваются остальные компоненты. И складывается впечатление, что сайт работает быстро. Как называется такая технология ? Отзывчивость ?
- Как потом индексируются такие сайты ? какие технологии используются, чтобы поисковые роботы могли видеть контент, которые рендерится из js ? Насколько знаю, поисковые работы сейчас умеют индексировать такие страницы, где контент загружается по ajax. Но что, если какие-то данные загружаются 5 секунд ? могут ли они быть проиндексированы ?
- какие именно компоненты (на примере интернет-магазинов) принято рендерить на стороне фронтенда получая данные из бэккнда ? если загружать таким образом по 10 компонентов по api, то получается достаточно много http запросов от клиента, и мне кажется достаточно сильно должно тормозить ?

Comment: Видимо Вы имеете ввиду `микросервисы`. Прежде чем принимать решение в их пользу я бы посоветовал Вам почитать о их преимуществах и недостатках. Не везде и не всегда стоит их использовать. Думаю в процессе чтения найдете и ответы на Ваши вопросы.

Comment: ответ на подвопрос 1: lazyLoad

Comment: 1. Это технология блочной верстки, используется для более корректного отображения каркаса сайта без данных, делают так называемые заглушки под каждый блок, чтобы при получении данных все не выглядело как перестраивающийся трансформер. 
2. Робот точно прочитает матетеги и все то, что отрендерилось сразу, далее да, может отвалиться по даже минимальному таймауту, я наблюдал, что бот ждет не более 7 секунд (это было самое долгое ожидание).
3. Это холиварный вопрос и однозначного ответа вам не дадут, вы можете посмотреть в сторону разных видов рендеринга (у всех есть как +-сы, так и --сы).